# Best way to check of a resource exists with express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Let say you already your list of valid resources

```
const  resources = ["foo", "bar"];
```

and your url path is

```
router.get("/resource/:resourceID" ( req, res, next ) => {
    //code here
    res.send("something")    
} );
```

What is the best way to check if a resource is valid?
Do I do a check for each GET,POST,PUT and DELETE? This seems so untidy surely there is a better way.

Comment: You can use the [app.param](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) middleware and do the checking once there e.g. `app.param('resourceID', checkResourceID)`.

Comment: @Mikey thanks add this as an answer, I don't know if it is the best way, but seems a lot better than checking every HTTP method, and you can also get a green tick unless there is a better answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [app.param](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) middleware and do the checking once there e.g.

```
app.param('resourceID', function (req, res, next, id) {
    if (resources.indexOf(id) > -1) {
        return next();
    }
    next(new Error('failed to load resource'));
});
```

Comment: I was going to use Array.some but checked and indexOf is quicker